# How do I open my application with the Launcher app file .desktop

Tags: bash, command-line, oracle-sqldeveloper, launcher, app-launcher

I've a problem with the application Oracle SQL Developer, I can only run it going to the terminal and only with the sudo command. My file is there : /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper and to open it I have to do sudo sqldeveloper.

Now here is the code of my launcher app :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Oracle SQL Developer
Exec=sqldeveloper
Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
Terminal=false >> ~/.local/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop
```

I've already tried to put the full path in the Exec row but nothing, the app doesn't launch, there's the icon in the toolbar few second and it dissapears.

Comment: Drag the app into your Applications .. run. That should be it

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Probably a Java issue, make sure you have 8, 11,12, or 13 https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-8-on-a-mac-with-sql-developer-4-1/

Comment: I have the java 11.0.5 version

Comment: Make sure that Java home is specified in the product.conf file then

Comment: Do you know where is the product.conf file?

Comment: read the link i shared

Comment: I realized that I didn't put the path of jdk in this file, but it still doesn't work, only with the terminal and with sudo command

Comment: if it only works with sudo then it sounds like there's a permission issue

Comment: I also faced same issue, googled lot but nothing get helpful.. BTW I solved this problem by adding absolute path in /usr/share/applications/Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop. If you want to run sqldeveloper from applications>programming menu then you need to edit your Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop file. add absolute path which is Exec=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper in my
 case also change terminal=true which show you other problem like java home etc, if java related issue then set according to terminal instruction after that change terminal=false

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, googled lot but nothing got helpful.. BTW I solved this problem by adding absolute path in /usr/share/applications/Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop. If you want to run sqldeveloper from applications>programming menu then you need to edit your Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop file. add absolute path which is Exec=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper in my
 case also change Terminal=true which show you other problem like java home etc, if java related issue then set according to terminal instruction after that change Terminal=false

```
  $ sudo vim /usr/share/applications/Oracle-sqldeveloper.desktop

    [Desktop Entry]
    Encoding=UTF-8
    Name=SQL Developer
    Comment=Oracle SQL Developer
    Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png
    Exec=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper
    Terminal=true
    Type=Application
    X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
    Categories=X-Red-Hat-Extra;Application;Development;
```

Comment: I have many paths to sqldeveloper.desktop, one in ~/.local/share/applications/sqldeveloper.desktop and an other in /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.desktop

Comment: @ADL92 Ignore /opt path it's installation directory it also have .exe extension file. use dir where all your  .desktop file exist. If it's .local/share/applications then edit in it.

Comment: @ADL92 run find command as root user to search all sqldeveloper.desktop.   # find / -name *sqldeveloper.desktop -type f